# bootstrap select box show the double select box. how & why?

Tags: select, double

this is the output generated why i applying the bootstrap select box

[image]

```
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <label for="degree"><strong>Stage/Level</strong></label>
                          <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option>Select stage/level</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                          </select
                </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: The is no double selectbox https://jsfiddle.net/melihaltintas/2uwd8qhy/

Comment: see this now you will get my idea